# Zend Framework 2: 403 forbidden error when trying to access localhost

Tags: zend-framework2, localhost, http-status-code-403

Hi everyone I'm new with Zend Framework and apparently quite unable to make it work.

When I try to access localhost the browser throws a 403 forbidden access error at me. Here's my virtual host file:

```
  NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName zf2-tutorial.localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/zf2-tutorial/public
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    <Directory /var/www/html/zf2-tutorial/public>
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI
    DirectoryIndex index.php
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And my htacces file wich is located into the public directory within the zend application folder on /var/www/html/zf2-tutorial/:

```
RewriteEngine On
# The following rule tells Apache that if the requested filename
# exists, simply serve it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
# The following rewrites all other queries to index.php. The 
# condition ensures that if you are using Apache aliases to do
# mass virtual hosting, the base path will be prepended to 
# allow proper resolution of the index.php file; it will work
# in non-aliased environments as well, providing a safe, one-size 
# fits all solution.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)(.+)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{ENV:BASE}index.php [NC,L]
```

I also have 775 permission for all files on that directory. However the apache error_log seems to think otherwise:

```
[Thu Mar 14 12:15:48.751980 2013] [core:crit] [pid 5755] (13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:60849] AH00529: /var/www/html/zf2-tutorial/public/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/var/www/html/zf2-tutorial/public/' is executable
```

Finally I also have FileInfo set on httpd.conf in order to allow htaccess reading.

So, any clue of what's happening here? Thanks!

**UPDATE:** I post the file list of /var/www/html/zf2-tutorial/public folder with their permissions:

```
total 28
drwxrwxr-x. 5 gerard root 4096 mar 14 14:01 .
drwxr-xr-x. 7 gerard root 4096 mar 14 11:20 ..
drwxrwxr-x. 2 gerard root 4096 ene 31 17:19 css
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 gerard root  711 mar 14 12:25 .htaccess
drwxrwxr-x. 2 gerard root 4096 ene 31 17:19 images
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 gerard root  303 ene 31 17:19 index.php
drwxrwxr-x. 2 gerard root 4096 ene 31 17:19 js
```

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the output of `ls -al /var/www/html/zf2-tutorial/public`?

Comment: There you have it. gerard is my username (I changed the owner of public folder to my account to check if that was the problem)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem using EasyPHP DevServ 14.

The problem came from a missing line inside httpd.conf file

**Require all granted**

```
<Directory "PATH TO YOUR DIR">
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from any
    Deny from none
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

in the virtual host setup ensure you have added

```
     Require all granted
```

but also make sure your DocumentRoot path is correct and you have included something like this for Xampp users:

DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/zf2-tutorial/public"

to enable access

Answer (score 0):

Ok problem solved! It was SELinux forbidding access to those files so I simply did what it recommended me to do on bash:

```
1. /sbin/restorecon -v /var/www/html/zf2-tutorial/public/.htaccess 
2. setsebool -P httpd_read_user_content 1
```

But now I have a more serious problem! The browser shows "literaly" the content of index.php instead of loading the script itself. The browser window simply displays this as a text:

```
    <?php
/**
 * This makes our life easier when dealing with paths. Everything is relative
 * to the application root now.
 */
chdir(dirname(__DIR__));

// Setup autoloading
require 'init_autoloader.php';

// Run the application!
Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php')->run();
```

Any idea of what's happening ? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your Apache server is running correctly?
If the apache server is down php files cannot be executed and are displayed as text